# Consulta mysql, condicional if y ciclo?

Tags: mysql

Con una  consulta que realiza el calculo de un rendimiento en mysql a varias tablas obtengo los siguientes resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo hago que se muestren sólo los datos de los embarques cuyo rendimiento sea  mayor a 0.
Hice un procedimiento con esto

```
set @rendimiento =(SELECT embarque.cant_bolsas_embarque/ (fruta.peso_kg*0.001)from fruta INNER join embarque on fruta.id_embarque=embarque.id GROUP by fruta.id_embarque);

    if @rendimiento>0 then select  fruta.id_embarque, embarque.fecha_inicio, embarque.fecha_fin, embarque.cant_bolsas_embarque, fruta.peso_kg*0.001 as toneladas, @r as rendimiento from fruta INNER JOIN embarque on fruta.id_embarque=embarque.id GROUP by fruta.id;
    end if;
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me dice que la subconsulta retorna más de una línea

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Por favor, ¿podrías aportar más información para poder reproducir tu problema? En particular, de dónde sacas `@r`.

Comment: es @rendimiento (esque al hacer la pregunta lo cambié para que se entendiera pero se me olvidó cambiarlo en el select )la variable a la que le estoy metiendo la consulta para calcular el rendimiento de un embarque

Comment: La consulta que hice para obtener a tabla de arriba es la que tiene la variable rendimiento, el problema al hacer la consulta es porque el rendimiento es diferente en cada embarque, si a rendimiento le asigno un sólo valor la consulta sí sale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es filtrar los resultados mediante una cláusula `WHERE` o `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
  fruta.id_embarque,
  embarque.fecha_inicio,
  embarque.fecha_fin,
  embarque.cant_bolsas_embarque,
  fruta.peso_kg*0.001 as toneladas,
  @r as rendimiento
FROM fruta
INNER JOIN embarque
  ON fruta.id_embarque=embarque.id
HAVING
  rendimiento > 0
GROUP BY fruta.id
```

Si la condición depende de una función agregada (como aparenta ser el caso, porque no aparece por ningún sitio de dónde sacas `@r`) deberás usar `HAVING`, si es independiente podrías usar `WHERE`.

Comment: Gracias Oscar! esto me dió una idea y ya me salió